# Why am I allowed to define a SendCompletedEventHandler for a static read-only field object, inside a non-static constructor?

Tags: c#, .net-core, constructor, static, smtpclient

```
private static readonly SmtpClient SmtpClient = new SmtpClient (...)


public Constructor()
{
   SmtpClient.SendCompleted += new SendCompletedEventHandler(SendCompletedMethod);
   // Above is allowed and legal. Why, when the field is marked as static read-only?
}
```

Any ideas why this is allowed? I'm really confused. Furthermore this will yield in an error, if the constructor is ever executed twice.

Comment: It is a reference type

Comment: You're not changing the `SmtpClient` reference though - you're only changing one of its fields.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The *field* is read-only, which means you can't change the *field* - but since `SmtpClient` is a reference type, the *field* is **just the reference**. So: you can't *change the reference* - you *can*, however, do whatever you want to the object *behind* the reference, if that type is mutable, which it clearly is. This is no different to:

```cs
class Foo
{
    public string Bar {get;set;}
}
static readonly Foo s_foo = new Foo();
//... later
s_foo.Bar = "we changed it";
```

Marking a field as `readonly` does not make the compiler treat the underlying type as immutable (unless we're talking about value-types, which have different rules). It *can't*, because any method (including property getters, which are just methods with a particular shape) could change the internal state without the caller knowing about it.

---

Note that for *value-types*, there is the concept of `readonly struct`; in *that* scenario, we are given the guarantee that methods *will not* change the internal state, which allows the compiler and runtime to make better decisions about how to apply `readonly` on fields that are value-types (and thus the field *is* the content); without `readonly struct`, the compiler makes a defensive copy of the value-type before each method call, to prevent the field changing; with `readonly struct`, it does not, as it trusts the type not to change. This is **not**, however, me saying "switch to value-types"; value-types are for very specific purposes, and they should not be used casually without understanding all the impact.

Comment: @LopDev: please don't edit out contractions; contractions are fine

Comment: the static keyword is what's most confusing. As far as I understood, we can't reference non-static fields in an instance constructor (non-static constructor)?

Comment: @SpiritBob you can access anything from an instance constructor; why wouldn't you be able to?

Comment: Because it's supposed to instantiate an instance of that class? The static fields mark them as being tied not to an instance, but to the class itself?

Comment: @SpiritBob *how* it initializes an instance of the class is entirely up to the class; it has every right to touch static fields - and it might want to do things like increment an object counter for non-dispose detection, or get state from a static cache. There is absolutely nothing preventing an instance constructor from touching static state.

Comment: This is really interesting. Can you recommend some reading material for the topic at hand? It can be in any form.

Comment: @SpiritBob I'm not sure what to say there; the totality is "there is no rule saying you can't do that" - it is hard to point of a list of zero rules to discuss them... can you be more specific as to what you're asking for there?

Comment: @SpiritBob the opposite is not possible, you can't access something non-static from something static within the same class (in fact, you can't access `this` from static because the static doesn't know which instance should be `this`)

Comment: I guess any msdn source, or blog, or something else, where they shine the light on the facts you're presenting.

Comment: Imagine a class `Scholar`. Every `Scholar`s have the same teacher, so, it *can* make sense to have a `static Teacher` inside the class `Scholar`. When you say to a scholar *Tell your teacher that ...*, the scholar knows who the teacher is. If you say the teacher *Tell the scholar that ...*, the teacher doesn't know which scholar you are talking about and the teacher may even have no scholars.

Comment: Even after reading about [static](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/using-constructors) and [instance](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/instance-constructors) constructors, I still couldn't find something that would make it clear as day.

Comment: @SpiritBob I don't understand the confusion, honestly; any code can access static fields, as long as the accessibility rules (`private`, `internal`, etc) are observed; since we're talking about a static field in the same type: it has access *whatever* the accessibility is. So... it can access the field.